# db.runCommand Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

After running this line of code

```
 db.runCommand({convertToCapped: "mail_logs", size: 29250000‬ })
```

in Mongo Shell, I get this error:

> Error: Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into the same issue, the problem was caused by the double quotes breaking the JSON command issued.

If you haven't solved by now, try

```
db.runCommand({convertToCapped:'mail_logs', size: 29250000‬});
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we just restarted the shell and it worked :)